# Using SciPy functions in EPD Free

Tags: scipy, linear-algebra, enthought

I am completely new to Enthought and SciPy and the EPD Free support suggested I come here for help.

I just started working through a course on Linear Algebra through MIT's open course website.  When looking for a free Matlab substitute I was directed to use SciPy/NumPy and matplotlib as the best alternatives.  The SciPy website itself recommended Enthought as the simplest install for Windows.

So now I have EPD Free installed on my system, but when I try to do something simple like sp.sqrt(-1) (which is the first function given as an example on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/basic.html) I get the error "sp is not defined".

So then how do I access the SciPy functions?  I am having a hard time finding an EPD guide for beginners, perhaps I chose the wrong tool for introductory linear algebra?

Thank you in all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import scipy before using it. Add the following at the beginning of your script or interactive session:

```
import scipy as sp
```